# Detect if cursor is in a defined area with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

I have a dynamically-set invisible area of `0.6 * $(window).width();` and `0.7 * $(window).height();`, centered at the page (so the area is positioned `0.2 * $(window).width();` and `0.15 * $(window).height();` from the `(0,0)` corner of the page).

I want the cursor to trigger different interactions based on whether the cursor is inside or outside the area.

```
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    var cursorX = e.pageX;
    var cursorY = e.pageY;
    var windowW = $(window).width();
    var windowH = $(window).height();

    if (0.2 * windowW <= cursorX <= 0.8 * windowW && 0.15 * windowH <= cursorY <= 0.85 * windowH) {
      console.log("the cursor is inside the bound, do something.");
    } else {
      console.log("the cursor is outside the boud. do something else.");
    }
  }
```

Currently, wherever my mouse goes, it only logs that the cursor is inside the bound. I think something is wrong with the if statement. How do I fix this?

**Edits:** please note that I also have a canvas for drawing with the cursor at the bottom, so I can't add a div on top to use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`. What are the alternatives?

Comment: make use of the `onMouseEnter` event https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ - attach an event listener on the given HTML element which represents your "area"

Comment: @messerbill but does this mean that I have to create a new div element as the area?

Comment: not only a div element but at least any html element - what are your trying to achieve?

Comment: @messerbill I also have a canvas at the bottom, so I can't add a div on top to use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`. What are the alternatives?

Comment: why does a canvas at the bottom keep you from creating a new element?

Comment: @messerbill it doesn't. the cursor is also acting as a drawing tool on the canvas. so if I create a new element with `mouseenter()` or `mouseleave()` functions, it will have to stay on top of the canvas element, which messes up the drawing functions for the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a logic error in my previous code. Writing the `if` statement differently has solved the problem.

```
if (cursorX <= 0.2 * windowW || cursorX >= 0.8 * windowW || cursorY <= 0.15 * windowH || cursorY >= 0.85 * windowH) {
  console.log("out of bound!")
} else {
  console.log("inside the bound!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What’s the element of that invisible-area?

You can set a div in that position, have a transparent as a background color then use mouseenter to detect when a mouse has just entered into that div (i.e. hidden area)

Have a look at this: https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: I also have a canvas at the bottom, so I can't add a div on top to use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`. What are the alternatives?

Comment: What is the element of the that "Invisible area"?

If the area is a canvas you can use the mouseenter and mouseleave event.

Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp

MouseEvent is in all all HTML elements EXCEPT: <base>, <bdo>, <br>, <head>, <html>, <iframe>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>, and <title>

Another link for more examples https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_over_enter